# Loading Multiple pages on the same page in PHP contd

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

This post is in continuation of the post in this URL [Loading Multiple pages on the same page in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183248/loading-multiple-pages-on-the-same-page-in-php)

Sorry, I feel this is a new query, so I thought of posting a new question..

Thanks guys for ur inputs there.. My core problem remains the same

"I have a basic HTML page named cwt.html which has all the checkboxes and submit button. Once the Submit button is clicked, the next page(say processing1.php) associated for the selected check-boxes(of cwt.html) should also be loaded in the same page.."

I used Load function call, that relatively fixed the issue, but I am being faced by another significant problem in the code.. It would be great if you could help me with that..

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Conditions We Treat </title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#submit1").click(function(){
$("#form1").load('processing1.php');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = form1>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "sickness[]" value = "Nausea">Nausea</input><br/>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "sickness[]" value = "Constipation">Constipation</input><br/>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "sickness[]" value = "vomiting">Vomiting</input><br/>
        <div id = "submit1"><input type = "submit" name = "submit1" value = "submit"></input></div><br/>

    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

The thing I need to do is, when I click submit, it should go to another page and process with this page's values..

The limitation I find here is

1. When I declare form action, it goes to that specific page instead of loading in this page, as in  if I give `<form name = "i1" action = "processing1.php" method = "get">,`  control goes to processing1.php and contents are loaded in a new page
2. If I dont give form action, it works in the intended way, but I am unable to preserve the data of this page..

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use an event listener on that form that catches the submit-event and then calls in your new page via AJAX. The jQuery API reference will tell you how exactly to do this: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Here is an example:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    // prevents the browser from sending the form
    e.preventDefault();
    // loads your nextpage.php into the target with the form-data sent as postdata
    $('#target').load(
        "nextpage.php",
        { postdata: $('#form').serialize() }
    );
    return false;
});
```

the `.submit()` is being called before the browser sends the form. Therefore you can use the native function `.preventDefault()` that will tell the browser not to do the default action on the submit-event. You can then make your own event-handling; in this case: loading your new page via AJAX and appending it somewhere in the current page.

`.serialize()` will create a string ready for submission via AJAX for example. http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Don't forget that the HTML retrieved via AJAX is per default not affected by the initial `$(document).ready(function () { /* code here */ });` call, you'd have to use `.live()` or something else to bind jQuery funtionallity to that new code.